# How are clock_gettime and getrusage related?

Tags: c, time, linux-kernel, clock, rdtsc

I am trying to understand how cpu time is computed in Linux. In particular, I would like to focus in this question on [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and on [`getrusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html). I'm wondering how are these two related.

- Does one call the other one?
- Do they both rely on the same underlying mechanism?
- If so what's their greatest common denominator, and by that I mean, what function from the [linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.9/source) are they both calling to get the time?
- And if they are not relying on the same underlying mechanism then why?

Comment: `clock_gettime()` is called through the [vdso mechanism](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html), while `getrusage()` invokes corresponding syscall.

Comment: I have no idea, but I love the question

Comment: The kernel link you provided has the sources for both calls.

Comment: @stark Yes. But for someone who don't know the kernel that much, it's very hard to clearly see what's happening.

Comment: @MiroslavMares and what does the corresponding syscall do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of clocks in Unix and Linux.  Some are wall clocks (CLOCK_REALTIME), some are modified wall clocks (CLOCK_MONO, CLOCK_BOOT), and some are CPU time clocks (CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID).

`clock_gettime` can pull from basically any clock that has a clkid assigned.  (Down in the kernel, there's basically code that, for each clkid, defines an appropriate `get` method for `clock_gettime` to use.)

I suspect, but have not confirmed, that `clock_gettime` with one of the CPU-time-related clkids pulls from the same CPU counters as `getrusage` does.

Answering your questions in turn:

> Does one call the other one?

I don't believe so.

> Do they both rely on the same underlying mechanism?

I believe so, but I have not confirmed this.

> If so what's their greatest common denominator, and by that I mean, what function from the linux kernel are they both calling to get the time?

I'm not sure.  (Sorry.  My work in all of this has been focused on the wall times, not the CPU times.)

> And if they are not relying on the same underlying mechanism then why?

Because the time-related code in the Linux kernel is crazy complicated, and tries to serve a lot of different masters.